# mkyaffs2image error in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, kernel, mount, permissions

What is the use of "mkyaffs2image" in the following command in Ubuntu terminal? How to solve the error given below.

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/mkyaffs2image /usr/local/bin/mkimage
```

mkimage file is located at the location /usr/local/bin/. When I execute this command, an error is displayed as "chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/mkyaffs2image' : No such directory or file exist". How to solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/usr/local/bin/mkyaffs2image` doesn't exist, just like the error message is telling you.

Check whether this is true by using `ls` :

```
ls /usr/local/bin/mkyaffs2image
```

If you get a "No such file or directory" error, then the file really doesn't exist.

The `sudo chmod` command that you're using is trying to change the permissions of the two files `/usr/local/bin/mkimage`, which does exist, and `/usr/local/bin/mkyaffs2image`, which doesn't.

Maybe you have a typo in the mkyaffs2image filename, or perhaps the instructions you're following are not correct. Alternatively, if you have the file somewhere on your system, you should move it to `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: The file /usr/local/bin/mkyaffs2image doesn't exist, I was a bit confused that mkyaffs2image is some command to convert mkimage file to yaffs2 file system or something to deal with yaffs2?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is normally a place to store local command binary files, so it could be meant for that. Your question doesn't ask what that file is for though, the command you've posted is just to change the permissions on those two files. If you're following a tutorial, there should be a step where you get that file from somewhere and put it into `/usr/local/bin`.